# Convert PHP file to HTML

Tags: php, html

(I use Wamp64)
I have a simple PHP file, but when I change the .php extension to .html, the page doesn't shows up correctly.
This is my PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    echo "welcome guest! please login<br><br>";
    loginbutton(); 

}  else {
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');


    echo "Welcome back " . $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>";
    echo "here is your avatar: </br>" . '<img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title="" alt="" /><br>';

logoutbutton();
}    
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my page (with .html extension):
[html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkvWA.png)

Comment: In `.html` file php statements is only text and browser print them

Comment: So it's not possible to include php code in html files ?

Comment: php files are "generators" of html, so it's not possible you can do oposite conversion html to php and then you can use php code in "html file"

Comment: Why bother with it? Why is there a need for a html extension?

Comment: Because with NodeJS, when I try to send the .PHP file, and open the webpage, I makes me download the php file, instead of showing him to me...
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try is not possible. PHP is interpreted by the processor, which runs the code and structures and output the processed code to your page.

So i think what you try is you have to Rewrite your URL from ".html" to ".php". So you have the html extension in your url but you send it to a php file. Without the php extension your interpreter will not work.

Other possibility is that you change your file extension for php and include the html extension but that is not really common.

[URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)